# Name this technique against Chudan tsuki ('knife' to the abdomen)

Tags: aikido, technique, identification

I'm trying to remember the name of a technique, if it even had one, and would welcome suggestions.

Uke and Tori stand facing each other, stance is unimportant. Uke attacks Tori with a tanto; its a straight lunge towards the abdomen - chudan tsuki.

Tori blends with the attack, at the last fraction of a second stepping to the left with the left foot, pivoting on the right, and raising his hands
such that both elbows are above the incoming attack arm and lower slightly to trap it. Uke is now to Tori's left at about 10 o'clock.

(this can be done either side; example only).

Tori keeps uke's arm trapped with right hand, and pushes to Uke's neck with his left elbow, grinding it into pressure point (or shoulder bone).

Tori then drops left elbow down and slightly backwards, while simultaneously bending both knees, dropping to a half kneeling position. This downward pressure causes uke to collapse backwards and downwards.

Tori finishes the technique half kneeling, left knee is upwards, right leg, per seiza.

Uke's arm remains stretched from his shoulder (on the floor, now pinned by Tori's hand) upwards and across Tori's knee.

(The point of this is to disarm and disable Uke and quickly return to a fight. The "unkind" version of this would result in an arm break, around the elbow).

So any ideas? More than 1 technique?

*Background: I trained for about 4 years at a 'hard' school, before switching to 8 months at a 'soft' school (Ki Aikido), after which I was no longer able to practice following a car accident (17 years ago). I have a hazy memory of many of the things I was taught.*

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a variation on [gyaku gamae ate](https://youtu.be/w3ZuJak1qwQ?t=67) where instead of a throw, tori controls and "pins" uke. [Here is another example from grips](https://youtu.be/Sjh-Mz-fhbw?t=122).

[Kokyunage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tyKVulDleCg) is the more traditional name of the technique.

---

<sup>The links will no doubt rot soon. However, the name of the techniques should be enough to look it up on whatever favourite search engine the reader uses</sup>